# Struts form validation with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, struts

Hello I have the following struts form:

```
<s:form key="frmInfo" action="insertInfo" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

And in this form I have the following:

```
<s:textfield key="b.name" label="Name" value=""/>
```

What do I put in my javascript function validate to check if something is entered for the textfield?  Should i be passing a parameter in?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an ID in your textfield element.

In your JavaScript you'd get that element by ID, check it for a value, and return `false` if the field value doesn't meet your expectations.

Note that [S2 supports some JavaScript validation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/client-validation.html) based on the default S2 validation mechanisms, although not all the server-side validations are supported on the client side, and more complex business-logic validations aren't supported either.

Also, while this is certainly possible (and easy) to do with "raw" JavaScript, I'd recommend using any of a zillion JS libraries to make things much cleaner and easier.

It wouldn't make much sense to pass a parameter to `validate`.